# How to create custom type (or validator) in ansible role argument specification?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I want to write role about network configuration, in my role many variable exist that only accept IP value. so I want to check this constraint in role argument specification. but I do not know how to do it?

As I found, this specification accept only few types such as below

```
str
list
dict
bool
int
float
path
raw
jsonarg
json
bytes
bits
```

And I do not know, how to add new custom type (IP type) to above list?

Or maybe role argument specification can accept some regex validator, but I do not find anything about that. and after I read [specification format](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#specification-format), I think ansible does not provide any way to add argument regex validator, but I want to sure does not exist anyway.

What is standard way to role argument validation?

Answer (score 2):

Roles parameters specification is a relatively new thing in Ansible, as per the documentation it was introduced in 2.11.

A common way to validate the parameters before that (or if you have more complex validation rules, like in your case) was to define a separate task file with assertions and include it as the first task to the role's entrypoint `main.yml`:

```yaml
---
# validate.yml
- name: Validation of role parameters
  assert:
    that:
      - ip_var is defined and ip_var is regex(ip_regex) # ip_regex is defined in role's vars.yml for sanity
      - # other checks
```

```yaml
---
# main.yml
- name: Validate the parameters
  include_tasks: validate.yml

# other tasks
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Many variables only accept IP value. Check this constraint."***

A: Use the filter [ansible.netcommon.ipaddr](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#ip-address-filters). For example, to test the validity of three variables *ip1, ip2, ip3*

```yaml
    - name: Validation of role parameters
      assert:
        that: "[ip1, ip2, ip3]|map('ansible.netcommon.ipaddr') is all"
        fail_msg: IP address(es) not valid
```

Either put it into the *pre_tasks* or into a role.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    ip1: 10.1.0.1
    ip2: 10.1.0.2
    ip3: 10.1.0.999

  pre_tasks:

    - name: Validation of role parameters
      assert:
        that: "[ip1, ip2, ip3]|map('ansible.netcommon.ipaddr') is all"
        fail_msg: IP address(es) not valid

  # roles:
  #   - net_conf
```

---

There are many options for how to test it inside a role. For example, put the declarations into the *defaults*

```yaml
shell> cat roles/net_conf/defaults/main.yml
vars_valid: "{{ [vars_ip, vars_str, vars_int] is all }}"
vars_ip: "{{ [ip1, ip2, ip3]|map('ansible.netcommon.ipaddr') is all }}"
vars_str: true  # Test validity of strings
vars_int: true  # Test validity of integers
```

and test it in *main.yml*

```yaml
shell> cat roles/net_conf/tasks/main.yml
- assert:
    that: vars_valid
    fail_msg: Variable(s) not valid.

- debug:
    msg: net_conf is running ...
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    ip1: 10.1.0.1
    ip2: 10.1.0.2
    ip3: 10.1.0.999

  roles:
    - net_conf
```

Comment: It is good solution

,So ansible does not have official way for do it in role argument specification?

Comment: No. There is no such type as `valid IP` in [Role argument validation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html).